# Divide participants over a number of groups

Tags: python

These are the contents of my databasefile.

```
Begintijd,Tijd van voltooien,E-mail,Naam,Naam2,Individuele reservering of een groepsreservering,Hoeveel mensen zitten in de groep,Aan welke onderdelen wil je meedoen.,Meedoen aan het simulatie programma
11-1-18 10:25:42,11-1-18 10:25:59,anonymous,,kenny meisen,individueel,,keuze 1,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:01,11-1-18 10:26:13,anonymous,,miguel daniels,groep,4,keuze 3,Nee
11-1-18 10:26:14,11-1-18 10:26:31,anonymous,,giuseppe collura,individueel,,keuze 2,Nee
11-1-18 10:26:32,11-1-18 10:26:54,anonymous,,rick van grinsven,groep,6,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,Berend batsbak,individueel,,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,aziz sjoeloeloelie,individueel,,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,cairo pizzaria,groep,8,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,kapsalon döner,individueel,,keuze 1,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,Kleine kindjes slaan,individueel,,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,Uhhh joaaaneaa,groep,4,keuze 1,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,schnitzel stube,individueel,,keuze 3,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,dextra champignonroomsaus,individueel,,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,darcy huppelduppel,individueel,,keuze 3,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,danny erendson,groep,6,keuze 2,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,brand bier,individueel,,keuze 1,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,karmeliet tripel,individueel,,keuze 3,Ja
11-1-18 10:26:55,11-1-18 10:27:08,anonymous,,daniel duinhouwer,individueel,,keuze 3,Ja
```

This is my python code:

```
deelnemers = open('C:/SpaceFrontier4.csv', 'r') #de database wordt geopend
deelnemers.readline() #de eerste regel wordt ingelezen
scheidingsregel = ('------------------------------------------------------------')


print()
print('|=======================|' )
print('|De database is geopend |' )
print('|=======================|' )
print()


def deelname1(): #print de deelnemers van lezing en workshop 1
    print(scheidingsregel)
    print('Programma voor de lezing en workshop over:', p1ond)
    print('De lezing over', p1ond, 'begint om', p1tijd)
    print()
    print('Deelnemers:\n')
    print(programma1)
    print(scheidingsregel)

def deelname2(): #print de deelnemers van lezing en workshop 2
    print(scheidingsregel)
    print('Programma voor de lezing en workshop over:', p2ond)
    print('De lezing over', p2ond, 'begint om', p2tijd)
    print()
    print('Deelnemers:\n')
    print(programma2)
    print(scheidingsregel)

def deelname3(): #print de deelnemers van lezing en workshop 3
    print(scheidingsregel)
    print('Programma voor de lezing en workshop over:', p3ond)
    print('De lezing over', p3ond, 'begint om', p3tijd)
    print()
    print('Deelnemers:\n')
    print(programma3)
    print(scheidingsregel)

def simulatiedeelname():
    print(scheidingsregel)
    print(simulatie)
    print(scheidingsregel)



p1ond = input('Wat is het onderwerk van de 1e lezing?\n')
p1tijd = input('Hoelaat begin de 1e lezing?\n')

p2ond = input('Wat is het onderwerk van de 2e lezing?\n')
p2tijd = input('Hoelaat begin de 2e lezing?\n')

p3ond = input('Wat is het onderwerk van de 3e lezing?\n')
p3tijd = input('Hoelaat begin de 3e lezing?\n')

simulatiedag = input('Op welke dag vindt het simulatieprogramma plaats?\n')

#print(data) #testen of de data goed wordt weergeven en goed is verwerkt
empty_str = ('')

namen = []
individueel = []
aantal = []
keuze = []

#datacontainers voor verwerking
simulatie = []
simulatie2 = []
programma1 = []
programma2 = []
programma3 = []

for line in deelnemers:


    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.split(',')

    if line[6] == empty_str: #wanneer iemand alleen is een vraag 3 niet invult
        line[6] = 1          #wordt dit vanzelf een 1

    if line[7] == ('keuze 1'):      #controle keuze 1
        programma1.append(line[4])
    if line[7] == ('keuze 2'):      #controle keuze 2
        programma2.append(line[4])
    if line[7] == ('keuze 3'):      #contole keuze 3
        programma3.append(line[4])
    if line[8] == ('Ja'):           #controle simulatie
        count = int('0')
        control = int(line[6])
        if control == 8:
            while count != control:
                simulatie.append([line[4]])
                count = count + 1
        else:
            simulatie.append(line[4])
            count = count + 1




    namen.append(line[4]);
    individueel.append(line[5])
    aantal.append(int(line[6]))
    keuze.append(line[7])




deelname1()
deelname2()
deelname3()
simulatiedeelname()
```

For my study I have to write a program in python which outputs the following results:
- A list of participants for choice 1, 2 and 3. (this part of the code is already working)
- A list of participants for the Simulatie Programma. (this part isn't functioning yet since I have no single clue of how to code this.

Whenever someone would like to follow the course 'Simulatie Programma', line[8] says 'Ja'. If line[8] == 'Ja', then the code uses append to copy their name into the list 'simulatie'. The code has to perform this action as many times as the value in line[7]. (so for example, when Liam reserves 6 spots, there will be 6 times Liam in the list.)
After this I have to separate everyone over 5 group with a maximum of 8 people per group. (line[7] can never me higher then 8). This is the part where I am stuck, I hope someone has a solution for this problem.

My apologies for the possible bad coding, but since I just started my study and do not have any experience yet, I have to use the knowledge I have which is not much.

Comment: In my answer I forgot to add the part where you need to seperate them into groups. What do you exactly mean by that? I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: You only read one line of your csv at the very beginning of your code.  You do not read the file ever again and should fix that.

Comment: There is a maximum of 40 participants, which will be divided in groups of 8. So there are 5 groups with a max of 8 people.

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
if line[8] == ('Ja'):           #controle simulatie
    count = 0
    control = int(line[6])
    for i in range(control):
        if count >= 8:
            break
        simulatie.append(line[4])
        count += 1
```